# React setState callback execution sequence

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
  var SubOne = React.createClass({
    getInitialState(){
      return {
        current : 0
      };
    },

    render() {
      var that = this;
      var list = [
        1111,2222,3333,444
      ];
      var createItem = function(itemText, index) {
        return <li key={index} data-index={index} onClick={that._handleClick}>{itemText}</li>;
      };

      return <ul ref="list">{list.map(createItem)}</ul>;
    },

    componentDidMount(){
      var that = this;

      setTimeout(function(){
        that._handleClick();
      }, 2000);
    },

    _handleClick(){
      console.log("before setState");
      this.setState({
        current : 0
      },function(){
        console.log("setState callback");
      });
      console.log("after setState");
    }
  });

  React.render(<SubOne />, document.getElementById("example"));
```

The result is:

setTimeout call:

before setState
setState callback
after setState

onclick call:

before setState
after setState
setState callback

why the execution sequence is different?

Comment: I think this is a good answer [link](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2893-setstate-state-mutation-operation-may-be-synchronous-in-reactjs.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with batching update mechanism of React. I'm not strong on the topic so I can't give you a clear answer, but maybe this discussion here would shed some light into you :)
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/reactjs/LkTihnf6Ey8

Answer (score 0):

`setState` is asynchronous. From the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate):

> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to `setState` and calls may be batched for performance gains.

Therefore you can only safely assume that the `setState` callback will be executed after the state has been mutated.